# What is the use of factory attribute in @component annotation in apache felix scr

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-felix

I have seen the use of @component annotation, but i cannot able to find the use of factory attribute in that. I have worked out below url but no explanation given.
[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FELIX/SCR+Annotations#SCRAnnotations-Component]. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain the reason for down voting

Comment: No idea about the down vote. I try to answer it below

Answer (score 0):

The scr annotations are deprecated now and you should consider to switch to the OSGi DS spec annotations.

I found a similar property serviceFactory there. See docs on [osgi.org](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.component.html).
It defines that DS creates one instance of the component per bundle that uses the service.

Comment: yes i found the use of serviceFactory, that belongs to "service" annotation. but i asked doubt in "component" annotation. do you have any idea about that.

Comment: I guess it does not make much sense to learn the felix annotations today. They might not be supported anymore in the next major felix scr version.